# How to change filled icon to not filled on TabView tabItem in iOS 15 Xcode 13?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, tabview, sf-symbols

How can i change filled icon to not filled on TabView tabItem in iOS 15 Xcode 13?

It seems now that the icons are filled by default...

My code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test_Home_V: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeList_V()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("_HomeTitle", systemImage: "house")
                }
...
```

Note : From iOS 15 you should not explicitly request the filled variant of SF Symbols icons, because the system will automatically use them as appropriate.

So how can I get my icons (SF Symbols) in outline like before?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To solve this, we can use `environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/symbolvariants/none

> Using this variant with the symbolVariant(*:) modifier doesn’t have
> any effect. Instead, to show a symbol that ignores the current
> variant, directly set the symbolVariants environment value to none
> using the environment(*:_:) modifer:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Text("content")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("tab", systemImage: "creditcard")
                }
            
            Text("content")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("tab", systemImage: "creditcard")
                        .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none) // here
                }
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: Result]

Comment: This is exactly what i want! Thank you Konomae!