# Change filled icon to not filled on TabView tabItem in iOS 15 Xcode 13

Tags: ios, swiftui, icons, tabview, sf-symbols

From iOS 15 / XCode 13 on unfilled icons (SF Symbols) in TabView are filled by default. Same problem as reported here:

[How to change filled icon to not filled on TabView tabItem in iOS 15 Xcode 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69319575/how-to-change-filled-icon-to-not-filled-on-tabview-tabitem-in-ios-15-xcode-13/69606313)

The mentioned solution does not work for me. Adding

```
.tabItem
{
    Image(systemName: "video")
        .environment(\.symbolVariants, .none)
}
```

throws following error:

> Key path value type 'WritableKeyPath<EnvironmentValues,
> SymbolVariants>' cannot be converted to contextual type
> 'KeyPath<EnvironmentValues, SymbolVariants>'

Anything missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can’t really answer your question with the information given. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I already posted my question in the context of the other topic. It was deleted there. So I opened a new post, referencing to the original post. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change filled icon to not filled on TabView tabItem in iOS 15 Xcode 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69319575/how-to-change-filled-icon-to-not-filled-on-tabview-tabitem-in-ios-15-xcode-13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: Project's build settings have to be set to **iOS 15 as minimum supported iOS version** in order to avoid the error message.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).